# GAE remote api getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am using GWT 2.4,GAE 1.7.2 and appengine-remote-api-1.7.2.jar.when I am trying to access my deployed app datastore on my different deployed app.on local or dev mod its working but in deployed apps its give an error on google app engine as follow

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/remoteapi/RemoteApiOptions
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:           com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-40e88cc1b5a9d01b(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedCo
```

Comment: Did you copy your `appengine-remote-api-1.7.2.jar` into `WEB-INF\lib` folder?

Comment: yes, i already put **appengine-remote-api-1.7.2.jar** in WEN-INF\lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot use this in a servlet scenario because of a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6349). Just verify whether the workarounds are of any help.

Also, reference [Google App Engine Remote Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688735/google-app-engine-remote-api)

Comment: thank you **SSR** i just put my code in RPC than its worked.Its means GAE Remote Api not worked with **Servlet and Restlet**.